# Using PHP in command line to read staged files in git

Tags: php

I don't really know where to begin with this as I am not very good at git, and am new to running php scripts via command line.

What I would like to be able to do is make a call in my php script (ran via command line on unix) that will figure out what files are staged to be commit, and return them preferably in an array.

- This script will be ran from home ~/
- The repos are in ~/repos/

I wouldn't mind passing in the repo name to a function that returns this array.

Comment: "I don't really know where to begin with this as I am not very good at git, and am new to running php scripts via command line." --- so you learn php basics and git basics and come with more specific question tomorrow. How about that?

Comment: "I could use exec() to run a git status but I wouldn't know how to parse that information back into an array" --- well - there is a **specific** issue. Why wouldn't you ask about how to "parse that information back into an array". It is *much* better than what you've asked for now

Comment: SO is not here to write your code for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Look at the format of the output from `git status`
2. Read the documentation on `exec`
3. write base script
4. test script
5. post back on SO for specifics
6. Profit

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$path = '/path/to/git/working/copy';
$status = explode(PHP_EOL, shell_exec("git status $path") );
print_r( $status );
```

Cheers

Comment: using `exec` would prevent the use of the explode... and get you the proper exit code.